# Does DM scripting have an equivalent to c++ pointers?

Tags: dm-script

As the title asks.  I am interested in knowing if the DM scripting language is capable of handling references and pointers, like you would find in c/c++ as `*a` and `&a`.  I'm guessing the capability exists at some level, owing to the way inbuilt functions like `fitgaussian()` work.  If this capability is open to the user, it would make it easier to code up some classes and functions I want to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does and it actually is quite *similar* to C++.
(But the simplification of the script language obscures it a bit.)

I'm trying to shed some light on it:

> #### All objects in DM (`Image`, `TagGroup`, `Component`, `ROI`, `ImageDisplay`, etc. ) are automatically and always passed by reference, not value.

You can see this in the following example code:

```
void ModifyImage( image imgTemp )
{
    imgTemp = irow
}

Image img := RealImage( "Test", 4, 100, 100 )
img = icol
img.ShowImage()
OKDialog("Act!")
ModifyImage( img ) 
img.ShowImage()
```

The actual image `img` of the main script changes. The routine `ModifyImage` received and used a reference to the image object.

**Hint:** This is a very typical source for bugs when dealing with `TagGroups`. When one f.e. gets a tag from an image and then modifies it in a method, *it changes the tag of the image!*

> #### In order to have methods *not* modify the provided parameter objects passed in by reference, one has to explicitly create a clone of the object first. For this reason, all the object-types in the scripting languages provide `...clone()` commands.

```
void ModifyImage( image imgTemp )
{
    imgTemp = irow
}

Image img := RealImage( "Test", 4, 100, 100 )
img = icol
img.ShowImage()
OKDialog("Act!")
ModifyImage( img.ImageClone() )
```

Now, the `img` variable of the main script is not changed. (Because we create a copy in memory, and then pass the reference to the copy.)

> #### However, primitive types (`string`, `number`) are by default passed by value, not reference.

Again, this can be seen by a little example.

```
void ModifyString( string tempStr )
{
    tempStr  = "Changed"
}

string str = "Original"
Result("\n" + str )
OKDialog("Act!")
ModifyString( str ) 
Result(" --> " + str )
```

Here the variable `str` of the main script is not changed by `ModifyString` because the values was passed into `tempStr`, and not a reference. The same is true for `number` type variables.

> #### If one wants to pass a primitive type by reference, this can be denoted with a `&` in the methods signature.

The example from above now modified:

```
void ModifyString( string &tempStr )
{
    tempStr  = "Changed"
}

string str = "Original"
Result("\n" + str )
OKDialog("Act!")
ModifyString( str ) 
Result(" --> " + str )
```

> #### The `&` can also be used for non-primitive objects in DM, if the passed in pointer is allowed to be changed:

Here is an example for this. The method does not modify the provided image, but instead creates a new one and passes back the reference into the pointer.

```
void ModifyImage( image &imgTemp )
{
    imgTemp := RealImage( "New Test" , 4, 200, 200 )
    imgTemp = iradius
}

Image img := RealImage( "Test", 4, 100, 100 )
img = icol
img.ShowImage()
OKDialog("Act!")
ModifyImage( img ) 
img.ShowImage()
```

> #### Finally: The `*` operator to denote pointers is *never* used in DM-scripting.

Comment: Thanks!  This is a great help.

Comment: @RWebster You're welcome. I'm glad to see good questions being asked here. Helps the goal of making this SO (sub)-site a really useful resource for scripting.